# How can I change the management console port of a wso2 is server using deployment.toml file changes

Tags: toml, wso2-identity-server

I want to run the management console on a different port or host name than the main SSO engine. I used to be able to change it in the carbon.xml as it was a separate entry. I cannot find a reference for the deployment.toml that lets me target different hosts or ports for the admin site. Any thoughts or links to a wso2 is deployment.toml reference would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configuring the `MgtHostName` via deployment.toml was not supported in the latest WSO2 IS release (5.11.0) as well. It was fixed with https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/11459 and will be included in the next release which is 5.12.0.

Until then, you can update `<IS_HOME>/repository/resources/conf/templates/repository/conf/carbon.xml.j2` with the change done in https://github.com/wso2/carbon-kernel/pull/2945.