# The WSO2 IS Management console url does not seem to be effective

Tags: toml, wso2-identity-server

I have a WSO2 5.10 server behind an AWS elastic load balancer. Per my original question [How can I change the management console port of a wso2 is server using deployment.toml file changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69417786/how-can-i-change-the-management-console-port-of-a-wso2-is-server-using-deploymen/69417886#69417886) , I modified the template and the server starts and correctly reflects the new management console url in the log file. When I log into it, it also indicates that I have logged in, but the browser simply redirects back to the logon page. Further, the original carbon management url is still active and functional. For example, logon.domain.com is the host name, idp.domain.com is the management url. Both display the carbon management screens, but the idp.domain.com url does not seem to function. No logs other than acknowledging the logon are apparent. This is a multi tenant setup, all of the tenant logons work fine
Any thoughts on diagnosing this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Assuming that you have more than one node of the identity server, have you configured sticky sessions for the management console from the load balancer? If not this can happen since the management console login session is bound only to the node that the login request is served.

Comment: Yes, the sticky sessions are enabled. I have also dropped the cluster to just one node to test and the same problem exists. I got around it temporarily by changing the base name in one node to the name I wanted to use for the idp and use the load balancer to route based on host names. Of course its no longer fault tolerant